# When can I omit return in javascript

Tags: javascript, return

I was practicing cross browser code when I realized only one of the function in the entire util obj I made required a return and I wondered why the others do not require a return. From what I understand JavaScript will return undefined when no return is called unless it is a constructor in which case it will return this.

I tested it with all the functions in the util returning the results of each condition and it worked. Then I tested it with out returns in any of the results of the condition but it did not work without return in the getTarget function.

Can someone help me better understand the reason for this?

the jsFiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/SusannDelgado/CnWzE/

```
    var evtUtil = {
    //cross browser Events
    addEvent: function (el, type, fn) {
        if (typeof addEventListener !== "undefined") {
            el.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
        } else if (typeof attachEvent !== "undefined") {
            el.attachEvent("on" + type, fn);
        } else {
            el["on" + type] = fn;
        }
    },
    removeEvent: function (el, type, fn) {
        if (typeof removeEventListener !== "undefined") {
            el.removeEventListener(type, fn, false);
        } else if (typeof detachEvent !== "undefined") {
            el.detachEvent("on" + type, fn);
        } else {
            el["on" + type] = null;
        }
    },
    getTarget: function (event) {
        if (typeof event.target !== "undefined") {
            return event.target;
        } else {
            return event.srcElement;
        }
    },
    preventDefault: function (event) {
        if (typeof event.preventDefault !== "undefined") {
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            event.returnValue = false;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need to declare return when you want the function to have an actual return value, whether it be a string, boolean, object, function, etc. If the function operates on something else, like adding an event handler or adding properties to something else, the return value is not needed. You could `return this` to be able to chain the method.

```
// An explicit return value
function getSomething() {
  return 'someValue';
}
var something = getSomething(); // something = someValue

// Operate on something else. No explicit return value
function changeSomething(something) {
  something = 'someOtherValue';
};
changeSomething(something); // something = someOtherValue

// Setting the variable to the return of a non-explicit return value
something = changeSomething(something); // something = undefined

// Return this to chain
var hash = {
  addProp: function (name, value) {
    this[name] = value;
    return this;
  }
};

hash.addProp('test', 'value').addProp('test2', 'value2'); // hash = Object {addProp: function, test: "value", test2: "value2"}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the chaining thing. I should have referenced that in my post.

Answer (score 6):

Return is used to pass something out of the function to the code that called it (generally speaking). Therefore in a function that doesn't need to pass anything back, such as `removeEvent` which is simply modifying the state of something else, it's not necessary.

The difference with `getTarget` is that as it says in the name, you're trying to retrieve a thing (in this case the event's target object). So in the code that calls `getTarget`, "something" is expected. As you say, without the return, JS simply passes back `undefined`.

Comment: ah I didn't notice that. Thanks. Your answer was very clear. So if I am asking for something I need the return to retrieve it but if I will just be executing a function I may not need the return at all.

Comment: That's right. Occasionally (in some languages) a blank return is used to end a function that doesn't pass anything out before it's finished, but as I say in 99% of cases, the above is true.

Comment: It looks like if you write arrow function in a single line, you are not obligated to write return statement as well! Because interpreter already knows that if you have only one statement it must be a return statement.

Comment: Sort of, but not quite. By default an arrow function will automatically return the value on the right; however if you wrap it in braces `() => { 5 + 4 }`, it will treat it as a standard function definition. You need to write `() => { return 5 + 4; }`. That allows you to write multi-line functions. If you want to return an object directly from an arrow function, you need to wrap it in brackets to prevent this happening `() => ({ key: "value"})`.